# Save function not working in Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, windows-10

I have a Tkinter program that has Save and Save As functions. I've got Save As working fine, but Save is not.

However, whenever I press the Save button it throws the error:
NameError: name 'save_as_dialog' is not defined

```
def save_as():
    notepad_save = notepad.get('1.0', END).strip('\n') 

    head_save = str(head_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n' 
    body_save = str(body_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n'
    tail_save = str(tail_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n'
    legs_save = str(legs_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n'


    save_as_dialog = tkfd.asksaveasfilename(initialfile = file_name, 
    initialdir = '/Users/Documents', title = "Save as", defaultextension = 
    '.txt', filetypes = [('Text files', '*.txt')])

with open(save_as_dialog, 'w') as output_file:
   output_file.write(head_save)
   output_file.write(body_save)
   output_file.write(tail_save)
   output_file.write(legs_save)

   output_file.write(notepad_save)

def save():

    notepad_save = notepad.get('1.0', END).strip('\n') 

    head_save = str(head_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n' 
    body_save = str(body_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n'
    tail_save = str(tail_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n'
    legs_save = str(legs_entry.get().strip('\n')) + '\n'

    try:
        with open(save_as_dialog, 'w') as output_file:
            output_file.write(head_save)
            output_file.write(body_save)
            output_file.write(tail_save)
            output_file.write(legs_save)

            output_file.write(notepad_save)

    except NameErrors:
        save_as()
```

As you can see, the file stores different information on different lines. This is a crucial part of the program, so I need to keep that part intact. The thing is, when I press the save button it throws the error:
NameError: name 'save_as_dialog' is not defined.
I've tried having the 'except' by itself and with AttributeError instead, but it still spits the same error. 
I'm stuck!

Edit: My new code, still not working:

```
global save_as_dialog
global opened_file_filename
global filepath

filepath = r"C:\Users\Documents"
opened_file_filename = None

def _open():
    opened_file_filename = tkfd.askopenfilename(title = "Open...", 
    defaultextension = '.txt', filetypes = [('Text files', '*.txt')])

def save_as():
    notepad_save = notepad.get('1.0', END).strip('\n') #

    head_save = head_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'  
    body_save = body_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'
    tail_save = tail_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'
    legs_save = legs_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'


    save_as_dialog = tkfd.asksaveasfilename(initialfile = file_name, initialdir 
    = filepath, title = "Save as", defaultextension = '.txt', filetypes = 
    [('Text files', '*.txt')])


    with open(opened_file_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(head_save)
        output_file.write(body_save)
        output_file.write(tail_save)
        output_file.write(legs_save)

        output_file.write(notepad_save)

    opened_file_filename = save_as_dialog

    time_saved_label.config(text = "Saved" )
    print(opened_file_filename)

def save():
    notepad_save = notepad.get('1.0', END).strip('\n') 

    head_save = head_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n' 
    body_save = body_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'
    tail_save = tail_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'
    legs_save = legs_entry.get().strip('\n') + '\n'

    if opened_file_filename is None:
        save_as()

    else:
        with open(opened_file_filename, 'w') as output_file:
            output_file.write(head_save)
            output_file.write(body_save)
            output_file.write(tail_save)
            output_file.write(legs_save)

            output_file.write(notepad_save)

    time_saved_label.config(text = "Saved" )
    print(opened_file_filename)
```

Throws the error:
*with open(opened_file_filename, 'w') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''*

Comment: Add `global save_as_dialog` at the beginning of `save()` function.

Comment: 1st remove `str()` from all your `get()` methods. `get()` is already returning a string. Your problem here is that `save_as_dialog` is defined in the `save_as()` function but you try to call it from the `save()` function. You need to either pass `save_as_dialog` to `save_as()` or make it a `global` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are creating the `save_as_dialog` variable inside of `save_as()`. The variable isn't defined in `save()`. Declaring the variable outside of those functions' scope should be the simplest way.

I'd do something like `save_as_dialog = None` in a scope containing the two functions and 
then add

```
if save_as_dialog is None:
    return save_as()
```

at the start of the `save()` function.

The result should look kind of like this:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

#  Filename of our file.
opened_file_filename = None


def save_as():
    """
    Opens a file dialog and saves stuff to it.
    :return: None
    """
    global opened_file_filename  # we wanna use the opened_file_filename from global scope

    opened_file_filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    with(open(opened_file_filename), 'w') as file:
        # write stuff to file here
        pass


def save():
    """
    If we have a filename, save stuff to it. Otherwise do save_as().
    :return: None
    """
    global opened_file_filename  # we wanna use the opened_file_filename from global scope

    if opened_file_filename is None:
        # it is none, which means we have not chosen a filename yet
        return save_as()

    with(open(opened_file_filename), 'w') as file:
        # write stuff to file here
        pass

# rest of your code
```

Comment: What do you mean by scope? I tried it inside the save() function but that didn't work? Sorry, I've only been learning python for the past 6 months, so I don't really know all the terminology yet. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Scopes are a way to limit where a variable exists. When you declare a variable in the root of your python script (with no indentation), it can be seen everywhere in your python script. If you define it in a function, it can only be seen in that function. [Look at this](https://pythonspot.com/scope/)

Comment: So, where do you think I should put save_as_dialog = None? Should I create a function with save() and save_as() inside, and put  save_as_dialog = None there? If so, how would I call save_as() and save() from within that function?

Comment: I'd put it on the same level as `save_as()` and `save()`.

Comment: Jakub. I agree you can combine the functions but I am not sure the OP fully understands you suggestion. Maybe add an example function to your answer.

Comment: save() and save_as() are both on the top level - they aren't indented in anything

Comment: Which is fine. You can define variables on the top level. It's not a good practice but it should work. I'll try to put a simplified code in the answer.

Comment: So, I've done what you said. Now, my only problem is that in save as I use asksaveasfilename(). It should produce the same as askopenfilename(), and it does (I think). However, the directory they produce has forward slashes, not back slashes. This, I think, is what causes the error:     with open(opened_file_filename, 'w') as output_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: You could replace the backslashes with .replace('\\', '/'). But I don't think that's the problem. Could you post your code?

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole code on pastebin, github or something?

Comment: I don't have a github, and don't know what pastebin is, but I can get an account. I've updated the answer for now, but I'll look into github

Comment: I made a github and put the code in there. I couldn't figure out how to make it code, so the github is just a text file/ My username is 'jacksonyukihillary' and the name of the project is 'Veteris'

Comment: So, `global` is a keyword used for using a variable from the global scope (root) inside of a function. It does basically nothing the way you use it. Use it at the start of a function to tell that the variable is "shared". What editor do you use for python?

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3. I like it because of it's simplicity, but it seems kinda limited compared to others

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you ever wanna have a chat about python, drop by on python discord.